# Understanding print in return statements

Tags: python, return

The return statement returns extra apostrophes and brackets, which I could not figure out why.

This code finds whether a substring is present in the string.

```
    def find(the_string, search_this):
     if search_this in the_string:
         a = the_string.find(search_this)
         # returns the unexpected 
         return (search_this, "found at", str(a))
     else:
         # the correct output I am looking for
         return (search_this + " was not found at " + the_string)

     print(find("qweabc","abc"))
     print(find("abcd", "xyz"))
```

The first return statement returns me with a print statement which is not desirable.

Example: `('abc', 'found at', '3')`

The second return statement returns me with a print statement which is the one I am looking for:

Example: `xyz was not found at abcd`

When printed out, why does the first return statement have extra brackets and apostrophes?

Comment: If you're wondering why the two returns give different things, have you tried comparing them? There's an obvious difference between the two.

Comment: @jonrsharpe do you mean comparing the outputs of the two return statements? Yes, have done the comparison by printing them out, but shouldn't the outputs be the same?

Comment: No I mean actually **look at the code**. You have two different lines that you expect to do the same thing but that do different things. So have you checked to see if the lines *are* the same? What are the differences between them? If you make them more similar, does the problem persist?

Comment: Hi, is your question solved? If so, feel free to mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression creates a `tuple` of three strings. In Python a `tuple` is similar to a list:

```
In [138]: ('one', 'two', 'three')                                            
Out[138]: ('one', 'two', 'three')
```

This expression joins three strings into one string:

```
In [139]: ('one'+ 'two'+ 'three')                                            
Out[139]: 'onetwothree'
```

The `()` in this case a just a grouping tool, and don't make a change:

```
In [140]: 'one'+ 'two'+ 'three'                                              
Out[140]: 'onetwothree'
```

To create a `tuple` with one item, such as a string, you have to include a comma:

```
In [141]: ('one'+ 'two'+ 'three',)                                           
Out[141]: ('onetwothree',)
```

In fact, it's the commas that create the tuple (more so than the `()`)

```
In [142]: 'one', 'two', 'three'                                              
Out[142]: ('one', 'two', 'three')
```

and for comparison a list:

```
In [143]: ['one', 'two', 'three']                                            
Out[143]: ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

This notation for strings, tuples, and lists can be confusing at the start, but worth learning well.

and one other variation - passing the three strings to a `print` function:

```
In [144]: print('one', 'two', 'three')                                       
one two three
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `return (search_this, "found at", str(a))`, you're creating a `tuple`.

You can do it like this (`Python 2.6` or above):

```
return "{} found at {}".format(search_this, str(a))
```

Or you can do it like this (`Python 3.6` or above):

```
return f"{search_this} found at {str(a)}"
```

Testing your example:

```
def find(the_string, search_this):
    if search_this in the_string:
        a = the_string.find(search_this)
        return f"{search_this} found at {str(a)}"
    else:
        return (search_this + " was not found at " + the_string)

print(find("qweabc","abc"))
print(find("abcd", "xyz"))


output:
abc found at 3
xyz was not found at abcd
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to replace 
`return (search_this, "found at", str(a))` with `return (search_this + "found at" + str(a))`

or preferably:`return "{} found at {}".format(search_this, a)`